# Crontab doesn't execute any simple command

Tags: linux, boot, cron, crontab

Logged as user `pi` I execute: `crontab -e` and I add this line to the end of the file, save and exit.
`@reboot touch /home/pi/Documents deleteme`

Then I reboot and I cannot find any file `deleteme` inside the folder `/home/pi/Documents`

Where's the problem?

These are the permission of the folder:

`drwxr-xr-x  6 pi      pi           4096 nov 24 09:50 Documents`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have:
    `@reboot touch /home/pi/Documents/deleteme`

And you should have `deleteme` file in your `/home/pi/Documents` directory.
What actually you're trying to do here is to update the date attribute of the Documents directory, but with the parameter added to it - "deleteme".
You can always check if cron tried to execute any of crontab line by looking into cron log, usually in `/var/log/cron`.

Comment: You are right it's only an error, `touch` works perfectly, but so I really don't understand why this doesn't work: `@reboot python3 /home/pi/Documents/my_script.py &` while if I manually write: `python3 /home/pi/Documents/my_script.py &` it works perfectly. I really don't understand

Comment: I may be wrong, but maybe `&` sign here makes problems? Cron jobs are executed as separate tasks anyway, so no point to specifically instruct to run in background. Also - try to put absolute path for `python` binaries. It is usually a cause of errors as well.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, also with `@reboot /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Documents/iceuploadbot.py` the bot doesn't start at boot. To be more clear sometimes it start without problem, other times (the majority) it doesn't work

Comment: Check the cron log in that case, if the cron at least try to start that bot at every boot. If it sometimes starts, sometimes not, maybe it is the timing issue - /home is not mounted. Can you move that script somewhere else? To a volume which is surely mounted at boot time?

Comment: Thanks, I solved, the problem was that at boot time the bot checks for connection but the LAN isn't already connected. I solved inserting a 5 seconds of sleep as first instruction of the bot. Moving the bot elsewhere didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

The most probably explanation is that `@reboot` is being executed in a moment that **/home** isn't mounted yet.

To be sure change the line to something like this:

`@reboot echo "test" > /var/tmp/reboot.txt 2>&1`

Then reboot and check if there is a file in `/var/tmp` called `reboot.txt`.

If that is the case, then move your script to a place that is present from boot time, for example */usr/local* and test again.